# Why is there no EMF induced or flux change of the left ring zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

[image]

I tried by dividing the system into three parts, and flux is increasing for the left most and right most part and decreasing for middle, but am not able to arrange this in form of a battery, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears we should assume the two rings make electrical contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As charges moving across a magnetic field, electrons get pushed down on both sides of the right hand ring.  Assuming the two rings are in contact, the electrons move back up through the two sides of the left side ring.  Both rings are carrying a current and are subject to forces. Since energy is dissipated in the resistance of the rings, an external force is required to move the right hand ring.

Comment: so emf will be induced in both rings?, that's where I am confused.

Comment: An emf is produced in the moving ring. A voltage difference between the points of contact causes a current in the fixed ring.  If you want to get technical, the changing current in the rings produces a small changing flux which alters the emf in each ring.